# Jackson ignore property of object in list property

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

One can ignore a property of a class using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`as a class level annotation. But let's say you have the following two classes;

```
class Client {

      @JsonIgnoreProperties ("owner")
      List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}


Class Vehicle {

      @JsonIgnoreProperties ("vehicles")
      Client owner;
}
```

I thought this would work. But apparently The `JsonIgnoreProperties` doesn't work on the list. I imagine it checks `java.util.List` for property òwner`but it doesn't find it.

What i want is a filter based on which object is retrieved first. If the `Vehicle` was retrieved first, show the owner but don't show the `vehicles` that Client has. And if the `Client`is retrieved first, show `vehicles` but don't show each `Vehicle`'s owner. This was too avoid the unending recursion.

My question is how can i ignore the property `owner` in the objects of `Vehicle` in the list `vehicles` in `Client`?

**EDIT**

Using @Kushan answer.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties ("owner")
Class Vehicle {

   Client owner;
```

}

This will always ignore the `owner` information. What I'm intending to get is if I have `Client`object and i'm getting it's `vehicles`, I don't need the resulting `owner` information of the `Vehicle`since i already have the `Client`object. But if i have a `Vehicle`object to begin with, I will need it's `owner` property excluding all the `vehicles` that `Client` has.

Comment: you must define some module with some mixins for your question.

Comment: @holi-java where can i get a good example of this?

Comment: my answer can't solve your problem?

Comment: yes. I say I have retrieved a `Vehicle` object direct from the database, jackson will ignore the owner property. I only want it to ignore such information when being accessed as a child of `Client`

Comment: could you describe your problem clearly?I can't understand your question clearly as you described ago.

Comment: serializing Client should be exclude Vehicle's `owner`?
serializing Vehicle should be exclude Client's `vehicles`?

Comment: let's say i retrieve a `Client` from database, I should be able to get it's `vehicles` but those vehicles shouln't contain the `owner` proeprty since i have the `Client` object already. But if I retrieve the `Vehicle` directly from database, I should have access to the `owner` . To me, field annotation would work nicely if allowed on objects in lists.

Comment: are you say jackson serializing or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are said,so I described all possible features to filter data when the data serializing in the Tests/Examples section.for examples:`@JsonIgnore`,`@JsonIgnoreProperties`,`@JsonIgnoreType`,`@JsonView`,`@JsonFilter` and serializing data by `mixin`/`rootType`.You could choose one which you like.

### Tests/Examples

```
package com.holi.jackson;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.NopAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import com.jayway.jsonassert.JsonAssert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor.FIELD;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

/**
 * Created by holi on 3/20/17.
 */
public class Jackson2SerializingFilteringTest {
    private final User bob = new User("bob", "123456", "bob@example.com");
    private final ObjectMapper jackson2 = new ObjectMapper();


    @BeforeEach
    void configure() {
        jackson2.registerModules(configuration());
        //write {} for empty bean
        jackson2.disable(FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        jackson2.setFilterProvider(serializeAll());
        jackson2.setVisibility(FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    }

    private Module configuration() {
        return new SimpleModule() {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                context.insertAnnotationIntrospector(filterIdAsClassName());
            }
        };
    }

    private NopAnnotationIntrospector filterIdAsClassName() {
        return new NopAnnotationIntrospector() {
            @Override
            public Object findFilterId(Annotated ann) {
                return ann.getRawType().getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Version version() {
                return super.version();
            }
        };
    }

    private SimpleFilterProvider serializeAll() {
        SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        //serialize all if filter not found,rather than throws an exception
        filters.setFailOnUnknownId(false);
        return filters;
    }

    @Test
    void serializingAll() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jackson2.writer().writeValueAsString(bob);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(3))
                .assertEquals("name", bob.name)
                .assertEquals("password", bob.password)
                .assertEquals("mail", bob.mail);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingAllExceptIgnoredProperties() throws JsonProcessingException {
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"name", "version"})
        class JSONRoot {
            String name = "jackson";
            String version = "2.0";
        }
        JSONRoot root = new JSONRoot();

        String json = jackson2.writer().writeValueAsString(root);

        assertEquals("{}", json);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingAllExceptIgnoredProperty() throws JsonProcessingException {
        class JSONRoot {
            String name = "jackson";
            @JsonIgnore
            String version = "2.0";
        }
        JSONRoot root = new JSONRoot();

        String json = jackson2.writer().writeValueAsString(root);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(1))
                .assertEquals("name", root.name);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingAllExceptIgnoredType() throws JsonProcessingException {
        @JsonIgnoreType
        class Ignored {
        }
        class JSONRoot {
            Ignored ignored = new Ignored();
        }

        String json = jackson2.writer().writeValueAsString(new JSONRoot());

        assertEquals("{}", json);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingMixInAnnotations() throws JsonProcessingException {
        jackson2.addMixIn(User.class, ExcludingMail.class);

        String json = jackson2.writer().writeValueAsString(bob);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(2))
                .assertEquals("name", bob.name)
                .assertEquals("password", bob.password);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingUseFiltersToExcludingProperties() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jackson2.writer(excludes("password")).writeValueAsString(bob);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(2))
                .assertEquals("name", bob.name)
                .assertEquals("mail", bob.mail);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingRootTypePropertiesOnly() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jackson2.writerFor(Contactable.class).writeValueAsString(bob);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(1))
                .assertEquals("mail", bob.mail);
    }

    @Test
    void serializingViewPropertiesOnly() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jackson2.writerWithView(Public.class).writeValueAsString(bob);

        JsonAssert.with(json)
                .assertThat("$[*]", hasSize(2))
                .assertEquals("name", bob.name)
                .assertEquals("mail", bob.mail);
    }

    private SimpleFilterProvider excludes(String... propertyNames) {
        SimpleFilterProvider filters = serializeAll();
        filters.addFilter(User.class.getName(), serializeAllExcept(propertyNames));
        return filters;
    }


    private class User implements Contactable {
        final String name;
        @JsonView(Privacy.class)
        String password;
        @JsonView(Public.class)
        final String mail;

        public User(String name, String password, String mail) {
            this.name = name;
            this.password = password;
            this.mail = mail;
        }

        public String getMail() {
            return mail;
        }
    }

    @interface Public {
    }

    @interface Privacy {
    }

    private interface Contactable {
        String getMail();
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("mail")
    private class ExcludingMail {
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: @obby I have updated my answer you can copy the test and choose one you needed.

Comment: much appreciated. Will try in the morning. It's 6pm over here. I will select answer as soon as I test tomorrow morning